# how to find out where customer subscribed to newsletter from?

Tags: customer, newsletter, customer-session, newsletter-subscriber

Is there  anyway to find out where the customer sign up to newsletter from.

i know the default way of subscribing is footer, but i am using the exact same way in different page also at checkout.

Is there any way to find out where they subscribed from.

Answer (score 1):

Within standard Magento 2 OOTB there is not really an option like that, if you will run: `DESCRIBE newsletter_subscriber`

It gives this, the standard table:

- subscriber_id
- store_id
- change_status_at
- customer_id
- subscriber_email
- subscriber_status
- subscriber_confirm_code

So no data available in DB to answer your question. The way to address your need would be for example to implement GTM and relevant tag fired upon each Newsletter Registration form and passing to GTM data like: who, when and from which page executed the registration to Newsletter.

Comment: hi @ Piotr Siejczuk thank you for that